# Showing that a given map is a regular surface patch of the unit sphere.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Show that the map $\sigma:(0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
> $\sigma(u,v) = (\text{sech}(v)\cos({u}), \text{sech}(v)\sin({u}), \text{tanh}(v))$, is a regular surface patch for the unit sphere.

So, I have managed to show that $(0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}$ is open and that $\sigma$ is continuous and injective. And, I know how to do my next steps, i.e., calculating $|| \sigma(u,v) ||^2 = 1$ to show that all points lie on the sphere and calculating $\sigma_u \times \sigma_v \neq 0$ to show that it is regular.

What I am struggling with is showing the remaining condition for $\sigma$ to be a surface patch. I.e., finding an open set $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ and a map $\Phi: V \rightarrow (0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}$ such that $\sigma((0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}) \subseteq V$, $\Phi\restriction_{\sigma((0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R})} = \sigma^{-1}$, and $\Phi$ is continuous at all points in $\sigma((0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R})$. I'm not sure where to even start with this condition, I haven't seen any examples of doing this nor can I seem to find any by googling. Any help is appreciated.

---

Edit:
After some trial and error I have found a $\Phi$ which inverts $\sigma$.

$$
\Phi\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{1-z^2}}\right)\\
\text{tanh}^{-1}(z)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

However, I don't think I even need to check that this does not satisfy the conditions above.

Comment: An inverse trigonometric function is never going to work to give you all values $u\in (0,2\pi)$ — even worse when you take $\sqrt{x^2}$. How do you prove that $(\cos u,\sin u)$ with $u\in (0,2\pi)$ gives you a chart on $S^1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes - I'm aware, but I don't know how else to go about this? I don't know what you mean by a chart on $S^1$? I don't have a deep understanding of this topic, I've just started learning about surface patches and I'm trying to get my head round this condition for a surface patch as stated in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your textbook must have done an example with standard spherical coordinates; you confront the identical issue with that.

Here's one way to do this, using basic multivariable calculus. Define a function $F\colon\Bbb R^2-\{(x,0): x\ge 0\} \to\Bbb R$ by
$$F(X,Y) = \frac\pi 2+\int_C \frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{x^2+y^2}, \quad\text{where $C$ is any curve in the domain from $(0,1)$ to $(X,Y)$}.$$
This line integral occurs in every multivariable calculus class, and you can show using Green's Theorem that $F$ is well-defined and then smooth.

By taking the circular arc from $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ (again, staying inside $\Bbb R^2-\{(x,0): x\ge 0\}$) you can evaluate the integral explicitly to see that $F(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) = \theta$.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but I have to be honest I really don't understand how this answer relates to my question, if you could perhaps give some more explanation and context

Comment: This gives you the mapping for the $x,y$ components. Your $z$ component is fine. $\theta$ is $u$.

Comment: I need a mapping $F$ for which $F(\text{sech}(v)\cos(u), \text{sech}(v)\sin(u)) = u$ though, not just $\cos$ and $\sin$?

Comment: Well, you supposedly had already figured that part of the issue out, hadn’t you?